# iOS 10 Push Notification API force touch & close button handler/action with Swift 3.x

Tags: iphone, push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I have been working with actions in Rich Push Notifications iOS 10 but stuck on following:

1. Is there any way to determine if a user clicks on "close or cross button" on notification (Image attached).
2. How to determine if a user views a notification on lock screen by using default "force touch" or "view action" (in case old devices)
3. Is above even possible with latest Push Notification API

[image]

[image]